# accHierarchy is a managed package throwing System.QueryException

Tags: trigger, soql, managed-package, query

I am using a managed package by Salesforce called accHierarchy. It's returning the following error in the picture[image: screenshot]

Any ideas on how I can get this thing to work?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is the knowledge article for this type of error. As it is a managed package, you probably won't be able to modify the query but option 2 and 3 on the following link may still be available to you.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000002493&type=1